# I can not get the loop to cycle 20 times and ask for a number between 1 and 6. Can anyone see what I have coded wrong?

Tags: c

I am trying to ask for 20 integers and count when then number 2 and 5 are selected with a static variable. This is what I can up with using code blocks. it is not asking for 20 number only 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int totalCount2(int ); \*this is where i added the function call*\
int totalCount5(int );
void output( int, int);
int main()
{
int count2;
int count5;
int yourNumber;
int yourNumberCounter;

yourNumberCounter = 1;
count2 =0;
count5 =0;

    printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 6.\n");
    scanf("%d", &yourNumber);

while(yourNumberCounter<= 20)
    {
       if(yourNumber ==2){
        totalCount2(count2);
        break;
        }
        else if(yourNumber ==5){
            totalCount5(count5);
            break;
        }
        else if(yourNumber <= 6 || yourNumber >=1){
            yourNumberCounter = yourNumberCounter +1;
        }
        else if(yourNumber >6 || yourNumber <6){
            printf("You have to choose a number between 1 and 6. try again");
        }

    }
 return 0;
}

    int totalCount2(int count2){
        static int count2only;
        count2only = count2++;
        return count2only;
    }
    int totalCount5(int count5){
        static int count5only;
        count5only += count5;
        return count5only;
    }
    void output(count2, count5){
    printf("Out of the 20 numbers you input. You entered the number two %d times\n You entered the number five %d times\n", count2, count5);
    return;
}
```

I am not sure if I am using static variables count2 and count5 correctly. I am studying from a book and think maybe someone sees something I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 6.\n");
scanf("%d", &yourNumber);
while(yourNumberCounter<= 20)
```

is outside of the loop

should be

```
while(yourNumberCounter<= 20){
printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 6.\n");
scanf("%d", &yourNumber);
```

The break statement terminates the execution of the nearest enclosing do, for, switch, or while statement in which it appears. Control passes to the statement that follows the terminated statement.

delete all the breaks.

also learn to use the debugger.

google: "how to debug c code" and the name of your IDE - the program you write code with.

Comment: I've placed it inside the loop and it will only ask once. I am not sure why the loop is only working one time. Thanks Nahum

Comment: @HHMOBILENOTARY If Nahum's answer addressed your problem, you should accept it.

Comment: oh ok. I will after I make the changes. I will now. Thanks for the reminder dbush

Comment: I made the changes and now the loop is not ending. It just asks the question and doesn't stop. I will continue to work on it

Comment: you don't increase yourNumberCounter.

thats it. learn to use the debugger!

Comment: I thought that's what I did in the second else if statement?

Comment: you do it only for 3,4
not for 2,5 you need to do this always.

Comment: Hi Nauhm, Thanks for your advice. It is working now. I made quite a few changes but understand a little better. Thanks so much for assisting me